# Compare 2 CSVs using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell to pull data and dump it into 2 different CSVs. I have this part working fine. I am using compare-item to compare the data in both CSVs. The compare is working fine however, it is not pulling all the data. I cant figure out if this has something to do with the files or with the Array.

Array Code

```
##Compares both CSV files and exports data
##Both files contain the headers but only File1 contains data for all the headers: "Project No.","Project Name","ProjMgr","FirstName","LastName","Status"

$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\scriptfolder\projects.csv"
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\scriptfolder\archive.csv"

$Results = Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property 'Project No.' -IncludeEqual

$Array = @()       
Foreach($R in $Results)
{
    If( $R.sideindicator -eq "==" )
    {
        $Object = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
 
            ProjectNumber = $R.'Project No.'
            ProjectName = $R.'Project Name'
            ProjectManager = $R.ProjMgr
            FirstName = $R.FirstName
            LastName = $R.LastName
            "Compare indicator" = $R.sideindicator
 
        }
        $Array += $Object
    }
}

$Array
```

Output:

```
ProjectNumber     : 0049
ProjectName       : 
ProjectManager    : 
FirstName         : 
LastName          : 
Status            : 
Compare indicator : ==

ProjectNumber     : 0205
ProjectName       : 
ProjectManager    : 
FirstName         : 
LastName          : 
Status            : 
Compare indicator : ==
```

File1 Example

```
"Project No.","Project Name","ProjMgr","FirstName","LastName","Status"
"0001","Project 0001 Name","005","Axl","Rose","D"
"0002","Project 0002 Name","003","Duff","McKagan","D"
"0003","Project 0003 Name","005","Steven","Adler","D"
```

File2 Example

```
"Project No.","Project Name","ProjMgr","FirstName","LastName","Status"
"0001","Project 0001 Name",,,,
"0069","Project 0069 Name",,,,
"0003","Project 0003 Name",,,,
```

Output File Example

```
"ProjectNumber","ProjectName","ProjectManager","FirstName","LastName","Status"
"0001",,,,,
"0003",,,,,
"00XX",,,,,
"00XX",,,,,
```

Comment: I think you're gonna have to post two sample CSVs for which you're only getting partial output - there's no way for anyone here to tell whether the output you've posted is correct or not given that we don't know the input

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Updated. Hopefully I did this correctly.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see the issue now, add `-PassThru` to the `Compare-Object` call - otherwise it's only going to output the value that it compared on, not the whole thing

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen and it was that simple....thanks! Sometimes its the simple things that are overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Compare-Object` outputs only the value that it compared on.

In order to make it copy all input properties to the ouput, use the `-PassThru` parameter:

```
$Results = Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property 'Project No.' -IncludeEqual -PassThru
```